# Where to add utility methods for DbContext?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, entity-framework-6, asp.net-identity, asp.net-identity-2

So I have an ASP.NET MVC 5 app with ASP.NET Identity 2.0 running.  Everything is pretty okay, but I want to refactor my code and I am wondering what alternatives exist to my current implementation.  Let me explain.

I have the Controllers in the root of my project as well as many in the Areas folder of the project.  Nearly all of them inherit from a `BaseController` class, which in turn inherits from `System.Web.Mvc.Controller`.  This `BaseController` looks something like this:

```
public class BaseController()
{
    protected ApplicationUserManager _userManager;
    protected ApplicationRoleManager _roleManager;
    protected readonly MyDbContext _db = new MyDbContext();

    public BaseController()
    {
    }

    public BaseController(ApplicationUserManager um, ApplicationRoleManager rm)
    {
        UserManager = um;
        RoleManager = rm;
    }

    public ApplicationUserManager UserManager { ... }
    public ApplicationRoleManager RoleManager { ... }

    #region Utility Methods

    // Here are over 60 utility methods that are basically queries on _db

    #endregion
}
```

More methods are on the way and I can't help but feel there is a better way than having them in a base class when logically, not every controller should directly inherit such methods.

Moving them to `MyDbContext` (inherits `IdentityDbContext`) essentially does nothing but move them to a *more applicable* file.  What I'm imagining is having custom utility methods for each DbSet in `MyDbContext` but I'm not sure how to do that.  Something like the following would be ideal:

```
Semester thisSemester = _db.Semesters.GetCurrentSemester();
```

or

```
SelectList semesters = _db.Semesters.GetAllSemestersAsSelectList();
```

where `Semesters` is of type `DbSet<Semester>` in both examples.

Can anyone offer a solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When I see a method like...

```
_db.Semesters.GetAllSemestersAsSelectList()
```

...I think this would be an extension method (unless you have your own implementation of `DbSet`). But extension methods are intended for really universal tasks, not for such specific tasks. Moreover, it requires that anywhere where you want this select list you have access tot the `DbSet`

It's better to do this in a service class so you can call a method like

```
_semesterService.GetAllSemestersAsSelectList()
```

This service could look like

```
class SemesterService : ISemesterService
{
    private readonly MyDbContext _context;

    /// <summary>
    /// Constructor in which an IoC container can inject a context.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="context"></param>
    public SemesterService(MyDbContext context)
    {
        this._context = context;
    }

    public SelectList GetAllSemestersAsSelectList()
    {
        return new SelectList(_context.Semesters, "Id", "Name");
    }

    public Semester GetCurrentSemester()
    {
         return _context.Semesters.Where(....).FirstOrDefault();
    }
}
```

Just to give you an example.

Probably it's even better to just return Semesters from the service and build the `SelectList` in the MVC controller, so the service layer won't have a dependency to MVC.

Comment: Hey Gert, would you throw something in there about perhaps how to restructure the solution projects (right now I just have one) with this implementation?  Also, would I still have the db context created with every controller or would each controller initialize the services it needs?

Comment: I think a sound solution structure depends on too many unknown (to me) details to propose one here. As for the initialization: without dependency injection, in my opinion a controller would initialize a service and a service its context. With IoC, the IoC container injects a service into a controller (if you go as far as overriding the MVC controller factory) in which it injects a context, all by constructor injection.